# How to get fresh page after pressing F5 or refresh icon in browser in MVC5 when errors occured?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my login page,when credentials are wrong ,it gives error.but when i pressed F5 or refresh button in browser,it shows same error page not giving refreshed page.

Comment: You probably resend the form. Re-enter the URL and load the page. (Just click on the URL and hit `Enter`)

Comment: You can also press CTRL + F5

Comment: but what if user press F5 or refresh icon.it gives you the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting F5 causes the form to repost. You cannot by-pass this feature since it's build in every browser.

You can click on the address bar and press enter. This way you will request a new page without form data.

If you want your user to been able to clear the validation errors then provide them with a 'x' button that clear these errors.